# sql not properly ended for three tables join

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, database-cursor

sql error for joining three tables for query`enter code here`ing common value to get reserved books by a student using cursor for iteration

I have tried to join them in reverse order

```
MEMBER PROCEDURE display_check_out(id varchar2)

IS
 cursor  curss 
IS 
select * from memberstable  AS m JOIN  reserv AS r  ON m.member_id= r.membs 

JOIN bookstable AS  b ON r.bookid=b.isbn

 where r.membs= id;

begin

 for curs in curss

loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student Id: '||curs.m.member_id);


 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  Name: ' || curs.m.full_name||' Gender: '||curs.m.gender);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Tel:'||'mobile: '||curs.m.telephone.mobile||'office: '|| curs.m.telephone.office);

` FOR j IN 1..curs.b.COUNT LOOP

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------------------CheckedOutBooks--------------------------');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ISBN: '||curs.b.isbn);

           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Publication Date: 
'||curs.b.date_of_publication);

           FOR k IN 1..curs.b.authors.COUNT LOOP

           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Authors: '||curs.b.authors(k));
           END LOOP;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checked out time: '||curs.checkout);
           END LOOP;
           END LOOP;
           END display_check_out;
           end;
           /
```

I am expecting to list user detail and 
list of books reserved by the user

Comment: Oracle does not use `AS` for table aliases (although it does accept it for column aliases).

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the cursor like this:

```
CURSOR curss
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM memberstable m
             JOIN reserv r ON m.member_id = r.membs
             JOIN bookstable b ON r.bookid = b.isbn
       WHERE r.membs = id;
```

Also there seems to be an `END` that is not needed at the end.

Instead of:

```
END display_check_out;
end;
/
```

more like this:

```
END display_check_out;
/
```

Comment: @ hol  The code produces an error like this               PL/SQL: Statement ignored
29/44    PLS-00302: component 'M' must be declared
31/2     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
31/42    PLS-00302: component 'M' must be declared
32/2     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
32/49    PLS-00302: component 'M' must be declared
33/2     PL/SQL: Statement ignored         As for the last end it is apart of member body definition. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: @yos Any typos in the table names or in the column names?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE book_typ AS OBJECT(
isbn varchar(20),
title varchar(50),
date_of_publication date,
authors fullNames_tab,
MEMBER PROCEDURE catalogue(bookobj IN OUT NOCOPY book_typ),
MEMBER PROCEDURE check_out( isb varchar2,membid varchar2),
MEMBER PROCEDURE display_check_out(id varchar2)
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE bookstable of book_typ(
isbn primary key not null
)
NESTED TABLE authors STORE AS authors_nt;
/
create or replace type books_nt As TABLE of book_typ;

/

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE member_typ As object(
member_id varchar2(10),
full_name fullName,
gender varchar2(8),
telephone tele_type,
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION member_typ RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
MEMBER FUNCTION show RETURN VARCHAR2,
MEMBER PROCEDURE reg_member(mem  IN OUT NOCOPY member_typ )
)
/

Comment: create table reserv(
reservation_id  number(10) NOT NULL,
checkout timestamp,
bookid varchar2(10),
 membs varchar2(20)
 );

Comment: @yos - please **edit your question** to add details or clarifications.  The Comments section is meant for, well, *comments*. In particular code is hard to read in comments because of the poor layout and formatting.

Comment: How is memberstable defined? Also there is a nested table authors that I could not find in the above. Did you try to run just the select as a single SQL statement?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE book_typ AS OBJECT(
isbn varchar(20),
title varchar(50),
date_of_publication date,
authors fullNames_tab,
MEMBER PROCEDURE catalogue(bookobj IN OUT NOCOPY book_typ),
MEMBER PROCEDURE check_out( isb varchar2,membid varchar2),
MEMBER PROCEDURE display_check_out(id varchar2)
)
/
CREATE TABLE bookstable of book_typ(
isbn primary key not null
)
NESTED TABLE authors STORE AS authors_nt;
/
create or replace type books_nt As TABLE of book_typ;

Comment: create or replace type fullName As OBJECT
(
firstname varchar2(20) ,
secondname varchar2(20)
 );

/

create type fullNames_tab as Table OF fullName

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is by MEMBER PROCEDURE display_check_out(id varchar2) which is a memeber of book_typ is to display a book reserved by a user by checking the id in the reserv table  along with book id (isbn) then dispaly the user information from the  memebers table and the boks he has reserved booktsable